# how to apply custom sanitation on inputs in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, input

I want to remove all multiple spaces from inputs (get) using this code:

```
preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $search);
```

but I don't know where to put this code so that it would affect all `$this->input->get('myfield');` ?

**EDIT**

maybe I wasn't clear enough.. what I needed is one code that can affect all inputs in all modules throughout my project. e.g. by creating a function in the libraries or editing MY_Controller.php

Comment: `<?php
   $search = $this->input->get('myfield');
   $search = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $search);
   
   print $search;
?>`

Comment: use trim and stripslahes to saniazi will protect u also from sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You can put as like

```
<?php
   $search = $this->input->get('myfield');
   $search = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $search);
   print $search;
?>
```

Comment: is there a way to make this code affect all inputs in all modules in my project?

Comment: Yes, You have to make helper and need to call in all module.